# Can I edit the sudoers file with visudo using my bootable USB

Tags: usb, sudo, password-recovery, visudo

Something I did with a `sudo dpkg ...` installation in an attempt to fix problems with my audio clobbered my ability of my sole user-name to run `sudo` in 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver). This is a single OS system. I have seen advice to enter recovery mode, but my Gigabyte BIOS interface does not show such an option. It shows no recovery option among the 5 choices (three of which are Ubuntu images.) I'm writing this from a system booted from a 16.04 image on a USB stick. I first followed the advice to remount the "disk" to be writeable with:

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /
```

I think I'm able to see and edit (using `visudo`) the `/etc/sudoers` file on the SSD where my "real" system lives. I added the line:

```
david   ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

... immediate after the `%sudo ...` line, and it was accepted by the syntax checker. So I removed the `.tmp` extension from the file name offered by visudo when I ctrl-O-ed out of the edit session and exited. Is this supposed to "work".

Update: It did seem to work in the sense that I can now issue `sudo`-requiring commands in a Terminal session, but it seems like a security hole, so I'm still wondering if I need to worry. Also wondering why I cannot get a Grub panel to display from a BIOS panel like I have read in multiple webpages and AU postings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should work. Just be sure you have mounted the root partition of your system and chroot to it before running visudo.

Comment: Yes. You reminded me that I forgot to mention that I did that with: `mount -o remount,rw /` I will add that to my question body as well. Any idea why grub cannot be found?